# MongoDB how to concatenate an array to a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, concatenation

I have a MongoDB collection document which contains a number of fields including an array for telephone. Some documents in the collection will have 1 telephone while others may have many. How can I concatenate the array to a single string without knowing the number of elements in the array, using PHP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the implode function...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

**Edit:** Based on a comment it sounds like we're talking about multi-dimensional arrays.  I haven't tested this, but it's probably a good starting point.  Also it was fun to write because it's a use of recursion which I don't get to use that often.

```
function FlattenNDArray($theSrc) {
    $retVal = "";
    
    if (is_array($theSrc)) {
        $retVal += "[";
        
        $srcLen = count($theSrc);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $srcLen; $i++) {
            if ($i > 0) { $retVal += ", "; }
            
            if (is_array($theSrc[$i])) {
                $retVal += FlattenNDArray($theSrc[$i]);
            }
            else  {
                $retVal += strval($theSrc[$i]);
            }
        }
        
        $retVal += "]";
    }
    else  {
        $retVal += strval($theSrc);
    }
    
    return $retVal;
}
```

Comment: I already tried implode, but implode does not work on arrays! It gives an error when concatenating normal fields and fields that are arrays (mongo arrays).

Comment: I wouldn't try implode on an array that can have arrays inside it.  I thought you were talking about putting chunks of a phone number together from a flat one-dimensional array.  If you're talking about building a string from an array that might have arrays inside it, you might have to just write a function that checks each index and handles as needed.  It sounds like a real-world example of when recursion could help you.